# Log4j warnings on linux

Tags: titan

its my first day with Titan Database, I just wanna ask if I should worry about those warnings ?! 
the link provided to help me solving this issue is quite complicated

Linux Ubuntu 14.04, and I did installed JDK 8, Titan 1.0.0 with Hadoop 1

```
Jan 17, 2016 5:04:20 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: aurelius.titan
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/phoenix/Titan/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/phoenix/Titan/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore the log4j warnings.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the warning - delete the file 'logback-classic-1.1.2.jar' from 'libs' folder.